# angular-formly, nested form, hideExpression does not work

Tags: angular-formly

Writing in the main field should show the child fieldGroup !!!, but only shows the sibling field !!! **'hideExpression' in 'child' does not work???!!!**

In this example it is that the field is not nested responds to its 'hideExpression' and nested group not, when they are identical.

```
vm.fields = [
      {
        key: 'sibling',
        type: 'input',
        templateOptions: {
          required: true,
          type: 'text',
          label: 'Sibling'
        },
        hideExpression: '!model.parent.main'
      },
      {
        key: 'parent',
        wrapper: 'panel',
        templateOptions: { label: 'Parent' },
        fieldGroup: [
          {
          key: 'main',
          type: 'input',
          templateOptions: {
            required: true,
            type: 'text',
            label: 'Main'
          }
        },
      {
        key: 'child',
        wrapper: 'panel',
        templateOptions: { label: 'Child' },
        hideExpression: '!model.parent.main', //why it does not work ???!!!!!!!!
        fieldGroup: [
          {
          key: 'child1',
          type: 'input',
          templateOptions: {
            required: true,
            type: 'text',
            label: 'Child1'
          }
        },
        {
          key: 'child2',
          type: 'input',
          templateOptions: {
            required: true,
            type: 'number',
            label: 'Child2'
          }
        }]
      }]
      }
    ];
```

[The nested group remains hidden.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBvlp.jpg)

JS Bin [here](http://jsbin.com/soronakupi/1/edit?html,css,js,output).
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, this took a long time.

The `hideExpression` command for the child essentially kicks in on the following

```
hideExpression: '!model.main'
```

This is **probably** because it somehow refers directly to the key of the actual element, irrespective of the parent key.Ofcourse, this is applicable only to this kind of `fieldGroup` setup, and the normal `!model.parent.main` works on others as in the case of the `sibling` element. This is really odd.

Here is the [working code](http://jsbin.com/hociwijure/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Also have a look at this [link](http://jsbin.com/dediratahe/1/edit?html,css,js,output).
Here the `child2` element is enabled after `child1` is filled.This too follows a similar pattern where in the fieldGroup, all references are directly by `model.keyname_for_the_field`.

Comment: Thanks for your help @ckniffen!